# Date picker age verification IOS Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Hello i am trying to make a date picker for age restriction on minimum 18 years of age, by picking date of birth in the datepicker then i want my code to calculate if the person is 18 years or older to be allowed to proceed to next step.

My code so far looks like this:

```
@IBAction func veryfyButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var myDateConverterObject = NSDateFormatter()

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

    let dateAsDate = datePicker.date

    let dateAsNow = NSDate()

    let interval = dateAsNow.timeIntervalSinceDate(dateAsDate)

    let convertedDate = myDateConverterObject.stringFromDate(dateAsNow)


    print(interval / 1000)



}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable names make no sense to me. If you want to calculate the user's age from the date picker:

```
@IBAction func verifyButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let dateOfBirth = datePicker.date

    let today = NSDate()

    let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

    let age = gregorian.components([.Year], fromDate: dateOfBirth, toDate: today, options: [])

    if age.year < 18 {
        // user is under 18
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! ... This gave me a really good understanding of using the NSCalendar. Tyvm! :)

Comment: I tried using this algorithm, however it doesn't take hours and zones into consideration